# Free Shipping in magento 2.3.3?

Tags: magento2.3

I have enabled free shipping with a minimum order amount of $100. When I add the product to cart with 1 quantity of $45. it works fine as it is not applied.

But It shows When i add the product of $90. However, it should have shown Free shipping when the amount is equal to $100 or above.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to sample data which adds cart price rule.

Rule name: Spend $50 or more - shipping is free!

Got to marketting->cart rule & disable the above rule. Then check free shipping == or above $100